# How can you enforce a setter method to be called on creating a object that can produce compile time warning or exception?

Tags: kotlin, oop

Suppose I've a class A which looked like this before:

```
class A(str:String){
  // body
}
```

Now, I want to remove the parameter from the constructor instead I'll be using a setter for that value. Like below:

```
class A(){

 lateinit var str:String
 
 fun setStr(paramsString:String){
   str = paramsString
 }

}
```

As I am using a setter for assigning the value, it wont give me a compile time exception while creating the object of that class.

So, I tried something like below:

```
class A(){

 lateinit var str:String
 
 init{
  setStr(strValue:String)
 }

 fun setStr(paramsString:String){
   str = paramsString
 }

}
```

This init block will be executed after creating the object of the class A where the setter method will be called.
But still what I want is to warn or throwing an exception when the object of the following class is created for calling the setter method.

Comment: could you write what you want to do and what you expect? From the code you posted I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I dont want to pass parameters into the construction of the class but expect to show compile time exception if i dont set some specific values of that class.

Comment: that would be null checking then, so the type `String` must be not null, the type `String?` is allowing null.

Comment: Your current code (second code block above) will already throw a compile time exception if you try to use `str` before it has been assigned. It will throw `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`. If you want to throw a different exception than that, you could write a property delegate class for it.

Comment: An `init` block is not "after creating the object of the class". An `init` block is part of a class's initialization and happens as the class is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

This here

```
class A(public str:String){
  // body
}
```

already has a setter, since yo can do

```
A("Bla"); println(a.str)
```

compile time errors would probably need some type checking (e.g. `String?` allows null, `String` checks for not null)

if you want to execute code on `a.str="Blub"` you do this:

```
class A(){
  var str:String = ""
    set(str) {
        // check some stuff here, throw Exception
        field = str  // if all is well
    }

}
```

you can also do similar for get() BTW.

Another method to do stuff on setting is using `var a: String by Delegate.vetoable....` and other `Delegate` methods - giving you high control over what's happening on setting a new value.

```
class A {
    var str: String = ""
        set(str) {
            // check some stuff here, throw Exception
            field = str // if all is well
        }

    var observableDelegate: String by Delegates.observable("") { p, o, n ->
        println("property: [$p], Old: [$o], New [$n]")
    }

    var notNullValue: String by Delegates.notNull<String>()

    var vetoable: String by Delegates.vetoable("") { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        println("property: $property, old: $oldValue, new: $newValue")
        newValue != "bla" && oldValue < newValue
    }
}

fun main() {
    val a = A()

    a.observableDelegate = "blub"

    println("Set value ${a.observableDelegate}")

    runCatching { a.notNullValue }.onFailure {
        println("Like expected: value not set yet, exception: ${it.message}")
    }

    a.notNullValue = "fuddder"
    println("Now notNullValue is set: ${a.notNullValue}")

    println("Vetoable now: ${a.vetoable} - setting to \"a\"")
    a.vetoable = "a"
    println("Vetoable now: ${a.vetoable} - setting to \"b\"")
    a.vetoable = "b"
    println("Vetoable now: ${a.vetoable} - setting to \"a\" again - should not work")
    a.vetoable = "a"
    println("Vetoable now: ${a.vetoable}")
}
```

output:

```
property: [var com.savinggrains.mwh.web.rest.A.observableDelegate: kotlin.String], Old: [], New [blub]
Set value blub
Like expected: value not set yet, exception: Property notNullValue should be initialized before get.
Now notNullValue is set: fuddder
Vetoable now:  - setting to "a"
property: var com.savinggrains.mwh.web.rest.A.vetoable: kotlin.String, old: , new: a
Vetoable now: a - setting to "b"
property: var com.savinggrains.mwh.web.rest.A.vetoable: kotlin.String, old: a, new: b
Vetoable now: b - setting to "a" again - should not work
property: var com.savinggrains.mwh.web.rest.A.vetoable: kotlin.String, old: b, new: a
Vetoable now: b
```

Comment: That top code block doesn't have a setter unless there is a `var str` defined somewhere in the snipped out code (`// body`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - fixed it with a default value